# How do I plot 5.234 as 5.2 and 5 as 5.0 in Pine script ? I basically want to show 1 digit after decimal point, even if it is a zero

Tags: string, pine-script, decimalformat

How do I plot 5.234 as 5.2 and 5 as 5.0 in Pine script ?  I basically want to show 1 digit after decimal point, even if it is a zero. Please Help.

It tried str.tostring(num, "#.#")

It works fine for let's say when num = 5.234 but it doesn't work when num = 5

Comment: You should paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
str.tostring(num, "#.0")
```

This will force the 0 to show up.

Comment: My initial input is 0.5. Then, I am multiplying it by 100, so it comes to 50. Now I want to convert it to string as "50.0" instead of "50". Above code you suggested isn't working for me. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @SantoshShetti I edited my answer, and test it, it works.